# Custom Swift Search icon, which opens search bar overlay

Tags: ios, swift

I have a top bar navigation with a search icon (image 1), i want to be able to click this icon and to have a overlay search screen pop up (image 2 & 3). I am new to swift so I'm not quite sure how to do this.

The code below is what I have so far to create the search icon.

But not sure where to go from here, I can't seem to find anything that can help me figure this out. Help would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXeT2.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FskZS.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Xto.png

```
private func setupRightNavItems() {

    let searchButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    searchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "search_icon").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    searchButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchButton)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UISearchController, you can init it with [searchResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618647-init), which is your second screen. Then when user taps the search button, you present UISearchController.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new viewController and put the functionality of image 2 and 3 in this viewController. Present this viewController when you press the search button from the first viewController.

2.or you can make a UIView on image1 viewController and put a search bar and table view in this view. just show and hide this UIView when you press the search button.